# How to listen to change to dangerous permissions settings in Android M?

Tags: android, permissions

How do we listen to changes made in the permissions settings in the App's settings in the device settings in Android M?

Comment: you can make your question clear by providing examples of what you are trying to do.

Comment: In Android M, in the Settings, in the apps section, for each app, there is a permissions section. How do we listen to changes in these settings?

Comment: you mean changes in permission for your app or other apps?

Comment: changes in perms for your app

Comment: Need more details for this basic issue?

Comment: AppOpsManager looks promising